# Disable auto-switching between desktops in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, desktop

I have Windows 10 installed, and so i like to organize my windows and sort them all in separate desktops according to type.

The problem is when I'm working on an application on one of these desktops and another application in a different desktop does any operation regarding the UI, showing messages or restarting, Windows would automatically switch to that desktop focusing on that other application without my well. This becomes extremely annoying when running a full-screen application.

How do i disable automatic switching between desktops? or how do i stop this using any other method? and if it's not possible what's a better solution other than moving them both on the same desktop?

Comment: No;  You cannot./

Comment: @Ramhound Can you suggest a workout for this problem?